# How to control bandwidth in WebRTC video call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc

I am trying to develop a Video Calling/Conferencing application using WebRTC and node.js.
Right now there is no facility to control bandwidth during during video call. Is there any way to control/reduce bandwidth.
(like I want make whole my web application to work on 150 kbps while video conferencing).

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: WebRTC is a peer to peer technology where the server just negotiates the introduction between users. Would you mind clarifying what/whose bandwidth you want to limit?

Answer (score 37):

Try [this demo](https://webrtc-experiment.appspot.com/RTCMultiConnection/bandwidth/). You can inject bandwidth attributes (`b=AS`) in the session descriptions:

```
audioBandwidth = 50;
videoBandwidth = 256;
function setBandwidth(sdp) {
    sdp = sdp.replace(/a=mid:audio\r\n/g, 'a=mid:audio\r\nb=AS:' + audioBandwidth + '\r\n');
    sdp = sdp.replace(/a=mid:video\r\n/g, 'a=mid:video\r\nb=AS:' + videoBandwidth + '\r\n');
    return sdp;
}


// ----------------------------------------------------------

peer.createOffer(function (sessionDescription) {
        sessionDescription.sdp = setBandwidth(sessionDescription.sdp);
        peer.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    }, null, constraints);

peer.createAnswer(function (sessionDescription) {
        sessionDescription.sdp = setBandwidth(sessionDescription.sdp);
        peer.setLocalDescription(sessionDescription);
    }, null, constraints);
```

`b=AS` is already present in sdp for `data m-line`; its default value is `50`.

### Updated at Sept 23, 2015

**Here is a library that provides full control over both audio/video tracks' bitrates:**

```
// here is how to use it
var bandwidth = {
    screen: 300, // 300kbits minimum
    audio: 50,   // 50kbits  minimum
    video: 256   // 256kbits (both min-max)
};
var isScreenSharing = false;

sdp = BandwidthHandler.setApplicationSpecificBandwidth(sdp, bandwidth, isScreenSharing);
sdp = BandwidthHandler.setVideoBitrates(sdp, {
    min: bandwidth.video,
    max: bandwidth.video
});
sdp = BandwidthHandler.setOpusAttributes(sdp);
```

**Here is the library code. Its quite big but it works!**

```
// BandwidthHandler.js

var BandwidthHandler = (function() {
    function setBAS(sdp, bandwidth, isScreen) {
        if (!!navigator.mozGetUserMedia || !bandwidth) {
            return sdp;
        }

        if (isScreen) {
            if (!bandwidth.screen) {
                console.warn('It seems that you are not using bandwidth for screen. Screen sharing is expected to fail.');
            } else if (bandwidth.screen < 300) {
                console.warn('It seems that you are using wrong bandwidth value for screen. Screen sharing is expected to fail.');
            }
        }

        // if screen; must use at least 300kbs
        if (bandwidth.screen && isScreen) {
            sdp = sdp.replace(/b=AS([^\r\n]+\r\n)/g, '');
            sdp = sdp.replace(/a=mid:video\r\n/g, 'a=mid:video\r\nb=AS:' + bandwidth.screen + '\r\n');
        }

        // remove existing bandwidth lines
        if (bandwidth.audio || bandwidth.video || bandwidth.data) {
            sdp = sdp.replace(/b=AS([^\r\n]+\r\n)/g, '');
        }

        if (bandwidth.audio) {
            sdp = sdp.replace(/a=mid:audio\r\n/g, 'a=mid:audio\r\nb=AS:' + bandwidth.audio + '\r\n');
        }

        if (bandwidth.video) {
            sdp = sdp.replace(/a=mid:video\r\n/g, 'a=mid:video\r\nb=AS:' + (isScreen ? bandwidth.screen : bandwidth.video) + '\r\n');
        }

        return sdp;
    }

    // Find the line in sdpLines that starts with |prefix|, and, if specified,
    // contains |substr| (case-insensitive search).
    function findLine(sdpLines, prefix, substr) {
        return findLineInRange(sdpLines, 0, -1, prefix, substr);
    }

    // Find the line in sdpLines[startLine...endLine - 1] that starts with |prefix|
    // and, if specified, contains |substr| (case-insensitive search).
    function findLineInRange(sdpLines, startLine, endLine, prefix, substr) {
        var realEndLine = endLine !== -1 ? endLine : sdpLines.length;
        for (var i = startLine; i < realEndLine; ++i) {
            if (sdpLines[i].indexOf(prefix) === 0) {
                if (!substr ||
                    sdpLines[i].toLowerCase().indexOf(substr.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Gets the codec payload type from an a=rtpmap:X line.
    function getCodecPayloadType(sdpLine) {
        var pattern = new RegExp('a=rtpmap:(\\d+) \\w+\\/\\d+');
        var result = sdpLine.match(pattern);
        return (result && result.length === 2) ? result[1] : null;
    }

    function setVideoBitrates(sdp, params) {
        params = params || {};
        var xgoogle_min_bitrate = params.min;
        var xgoogle_max_bitrate = params.max;

        var sdpLines = sdp.split('\r\n');

        // VP8
        var vp8Index = findLine(sdpLines, 'a=rtpmap', 'VP8/90000');
        var vp8Payload;
        if (vp8Index) {
            vp8Payload = getCodecPayloadType(sdpLines[vp8Index]);
        }

        if (!vp8Payload) {
            return sdp;
        }

        var rtxIndex = findLine(sdpLines, 'a=rtpmap', 'rtx/90000');
        var rtxPayload;
        if (rtxIndex) {
            rtxPayload = getCodecPayloadType(sdpLines[rtxIndex]);
        }

        if (!rtxIndex) {
            return sdp;
        }

        var rtxFmtpLineIndex = findLine(sdpLines, 'a=fmtp:' + rtxPayload.toString());
        if (rtxFmtpLineIndex !== null) {
            var appendrtxNext = '\r\n';
            appendrtxNext += 'a=fmtp:' + vp8Payload + ' x-google-min-bitrate=' + (xgoogle_min_bitrate || '228') + '; x-google-max-bitrate=' + (xgoogle_max_bitrate || '228');
            sdpLines[rtxFmtpLineIndex] = sdpLines[rtxFmtpLineIndex].concat(appendrtxNext);
            sdp = sdpLines.join('\r\n');
        }

        return sdp;
    }

    function setOpusAttributes(sdp, params) {
        params = params || {};

        var sdpLines = sdp.split('\r\n');

        // Opus
        var opusIndex = findLine(sdpLines, 'a=rtpmap', 'opus/48000');
        var opusPayload;
        if (opusIndex) {
            opusPayload = getCodecPayloadType(sdpLines[opusIndex]);
        }

        if (!opusPayload) {
            return sdp;
        }

        var opusFmtpLineIndex = findLine(sdpLines, 'a=fmtp:' + opusPayload.toString());
        if (opusFmtpLineIndex === null) {
            return sdp;
        }

        var appendOpusNext = '';
        appendOpusNext += '; stereo=' + (typeof params.stereo != 'undefined' ? params.stereo : '1');
        appendOpusNext += '; sprop-stereo=' + (typeof params['sprop-stereo'] != 'undefined' ? params['sprop-stereo'] : '1');

        if (typeof params.maxaveragebitrate != 'undefined') {
            appendOpusNext += '; maxaveragebitrate=' + (params.maxaveragebitrate || 128 * 1024 * 8);
        }

        if (typeof params.maxplaybackrate != 'undefined') {
            appendOpusNext += '; maxplaybackrate=' + (params.maxplaybackrate || 128 * 1024 * 8);
        }

        if (typeof params.cbr != 'undefined') {
            appendOpusNext += '; cbr=' + (typeof params.cbr != 'undefined' ? params.cbr : '1');
        }

        if (typeof params.useinbandfec != 'undefined') {
            appendOpusNext += '; useinbandfec=' + params.useinbandfec;
        }

        if (typeof params.usedtx != 'undefined') {
            appendOpusNext += '; usedtx=' + params.usedtx;
        }

        if (typeof params.maxptime != 'undefined') {
            appendOpusNext += '\r\na=maxptime:' + params.maxptime;
        }

        sdpLines[opusFmtpLineIndex] = sdpLines[opusFmtpLineIndex].concat(appendOpusNext);

        sdp = sdpLines.join('\r\n');
        return sdp;
    }

    return {
        setApplicationSpecificBandwidth: function(sdp, bandwidth, isScreen) {
            return setBAS(sdp, bandwidth, isScreen);
        },
        setVideoBitrates: function(sdp, params) {
            return setVideoBitrates(sdp, params);
        },
        setOpusAttributes: function(sdp, params) {
            return setOpusAttributes(sdp, params);
        }
    };
})();
```

**Here is how to set advance opus bitrate parameters:**

```
sdp = BandwidthHandler.setOpusAttributes(sdp, {
    'stereo': 0, // to disable stereo (to force mono audio)
    'sprop-stereo': 1,
    'maxaveragebitrate': 500 * 1024 * 8, // 500 kbits
    'maxplaybackrate': 500 * 1024 * 8, // 500 kbits
    'cbr': 0, // disable cbr
    'useinbandfec': 1, // use inband fec
    'usedtx': 1, // use dtx
    'maxptime': 3
});
```

Comment: You gave your answer over a year ago, does this still work? I have been trying to get it to work without success. Rather than using the library on the link, I am simply using the code you have posted.

Comment: It still works in chrome for "video-tracks". b=AS for audio-tracks has known bugs in chrome which is fixed in Chrome-39. For chrome 38 and earlier [for audio-tracks], you can modify SDP for "maxaveragebitrate" instead, as you can see some snippets [here](http://www.rtcmulticonnection.org/docs/processSdp/).

Comment: Thanks for the response. What method would you use to verify the limited bandwidth? My tests have shown no change. What are the valid values for bandwidth? Going below 30 I seem to lose video entirely. Thanks again.

Comment: This [webrtc-pedia](https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/webrtcpedia/) page listed some min/max bitrate values for VP8 and Opus codecs. BTW, it isn't easy to check available bandwidth. [Ref-1](http://testmy.net/auto) / [Ref-2](https://github.com/muaz-khan/getStats/blob/master/getStats.js#L62). BTW, 20kbits is minimum bandwidth supported for VP8, and 30kbits is minimum for Opus.

Comment: Is it also possible to limit the bandwidth of the a remote description and thus force the peer to lower its bandwidths? My use case: If I communicate with older devices like iPad 3, I can only use 240p and a framerate of 10. Otherwise, the connection will be lousy. But I don't want to setup the whole getUserMedia() thing again, since it would cause Firefox to ask for permission again.

Comment: I had to escape all the slashes for it to work. /a=mid:video\\r\\n/g , 'a=mid:video\\r\\nb=AS:128\\r\\n

Comment: I'm using Chrome 72 and latest webrtc [adapter](https://github.com/webrtcHacks/adapter) and mid is always `a=mid:0`, so it won't match `a=mid:video`. Unless there's a problem in the adapter, the bandwidth handler should be updated to find video information somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe this solution works with web, but iOS Objective-C library deny to work properly.

Answer (score 7):

A more up-to-date answer

```
const videobitrate = 20000;
var offer = pc.localDescription;
// Set bandwidth for video
offer.sdp = offer.sdp.replace(/(m=video.*\r\n)/g, `$1b=AS:${videobitrate}\r\n`);
pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
```

Explanation: `a=mid:video` is not a guaranteed tag. For receive only video, you might not see it or see `a=mid:0`. Generally it's a better bet to look for the `m=video xxxx xxxx` (or similar audio) tag and append the bandwidth parameters underneath

Comment: Is this valid?  According to the spec (https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-ietf-rtcweb-jsep-26), "The m= line MUST be followed immedately by a c= line".  I suppose the `b=` should go below that?

Comment: This works for me in both chrome and with webrtc native api. YMMV as webrtc itself is a pretty quickly evolving standard.

Comment: It is possible best solution today. But i tried to set any `videobitrate` value, from 10 to 20000, in test webrtc broadcasts (from one pc but different browsers) - eyes not detected any quality changes

Comment: use webrtc stats api to probe the bandwidth rather than relying on eyes. Bandwidth is required by higher quality frames but bandwidth alone doesn't guarantee quality. Check the source and encoder if bandwidth seems to be correct but viewing experience is subpar.

Comment: @Brad is right, see this link for a more complete answer: https://webrtchacks.com/limit-webrtc-bandwidth-sdp/

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this helps, but you can limit the video resolution from getUserMedia with constraints: see demo at [simpl.info/getusermedia/constraints/](http://simpl.info/getusermedia/constraints/).

Comment: Is it possible to change the video resolution in middle of the conversation. PS: I have kurento setup if that helps. Though I am looking at SFU solution instead of MCU

Comment: @bugwheels94 Yes, use `applyConstraints`.

Answer (score 1):

**I did it Yesterday and it works like a charm! in my case, it was needed to prevent slow and old phones get freeze during a videocall! have a look**

```
function handle_offer_sdp(offer) {
    let sdp = offer.sdp.split('\r\n');//convert to an concatenable array
    let new_sdp = '';
    let position = null;
    sdp = sdp.slice(0, -1); //remove the last comma ','
    for(let i = 0; i < sdp.length; i++) {//look if exists already a b=AS:XXX line
        if(sdp[i].match(/b=AS:/)) {
            position = i; //mark the position
        }
    }
    if(position) {
        sdp.splice(position, 1);//remove if exists
    }
    for(let i = 0; i < sdp.length; i++) {
        if(sdp[i].match(/m=video/)) {//modify and add the new lines for video
            new_sdp += sdp[i] + '\r\n' + 'b=AS:' + '128' + '\r\n';
        }
        else {
            if(sdp[i].match(/m=audio/)) { //modify and add the new lines for audio
                new_sdp += sdp[i] + '\r\n' + 'b=AS:' + 64 + '\r\n';
            }
            else {
                new_sdp += sdp[i] + '\r\n';
            }
        }
    }
    return new_sdp; //return the new sdp
}
pc.createOffer(function(offer) {
    offer.sdp = handle_offer_sdp(offer); //invoke function saving the new sdp
    pc.setLocalDescription(offer);
}, function(error) {
    console.log('error -> ' + error);
});
```

Comment: Hi, What is the effect of setting the bitrate by manipulating the SDP versus setting a maximum birate on the sender via the sender.setParams? thanks,

Comment: Hi, the related reasons because I do this, are old phones or low performance phones, in my experience, setting the maximun bitrate in a webRTC session causes old phones or low performance ones freezed videos, they can not perform well HD or high frame rate.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not for node.js, but maybe someone stuck with controlling webrtc bandwidth while developing a native phone app (iOS, android).

So, at least in version *GoogleWebRTC (1.1.31999)* for iOS and *org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.22672* for android there is method in **PeerConnection** instance.

For iOS:

```
let updateBitrateSuccessful = pc.setBweMinBitrateBps(300000, currentBitrateBps: 1000000, maxBitrateBps: 3000000)
print("Update rtc connection bitrate " + (updateBitrateSuccessful ? "successful" : "failed"))
```

Respectively, for Android:

```
boolean updateBitrateSuccessful = pc.setBitrate(300000, 1000000, 3000000);
Log.d("AppLog", "Update rtc connection bitrate " + (updateBitrateSuccessful ? "successful" : "failed"));
```

Comment: I believe there some confusion with bandwidth estimation and video bitrate. The AS: SDP flag can be used to increase or reduce video bitrate. The pc.setBitrate call can be used to lower or increase the network bitrate. By default the network bitrate will automatically adapt to the AS flag unless manually restricted via the setBitrate call.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what SFU media server you're using. But in short, your media server needs to tell the client browser what maximum bitrate it should send, by setting the bandwidth attribute in the *answer* SDP, as well as in the REMB message it periodically sends.

The REMB (receiver estimated maximum bitrate) applies separately to audio and video streams (at least on desktop Chrome and Firefox that I tested). So if REMB is set to 75kps and you have one audio and one video stream, then each will confine to 75kps for a total transport bitrate of 150kps.  You should use chrome://webrtc-internals to test and verify this.

If you are using OPUS as the audio codec, you can control the audio bandwidth separately by setting the maxaveragebitrate attribute in the *answer* SDP.  Setting this attribute will override the REMB value (verified on Chrome). So you can set audio bitrate to 16kps and the video bitrate (via REMB) to 134kps for a combined transport bitrate of 150.

Note that the REMB is sent by your server, so your server needs to support this. The other SDP attributes can be manipulated on the client side by modifying the *answer* SDP that you receive, right before passing it to setRemoteDescription().

This is my limited understanding based on online research. It's not based on deep knowledge of the technology stack, so please take it with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1):

Check this, this works for me.

Control your bitrate via getSenders(), after peer is connected then you can set your maximum bitrate.

This method allow you to control bitrate without renegotiation. so,
you can change the streaming quality during a call

```
    //bandwidth => "unlimited", 75 kbps, 250 kbps, 1000 kbps, 2000 kbps
    var bandwidth = 75;
    
    const sender = pc1.getSenders()[0];
    const parameters = sender.getParameters();
    if (!parameters.encodings) {
      parameters.encodings = [{}];
    }
    if (bandwidth === 'unlimited') {
      delete parameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate;
    } else {
      parameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate = bandwidth * 1000;
    }
    sender.setParameters(parameters)
        .then(() => {
          // on success
        })
        .catch(e => console.error(e));
```

[Reference code & demo](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/)

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use bandwidth constraints on the stream ([see this demo](http://webrtc.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/js/demos/html/constraints-and-stats.html)), but it doesn't appear to be working, even in the latest canary (29.0.1529.3).

There's some discussion of the SDP-based approach on the [discuss-webrtc](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/discuss-webrtc/xawlhG9jKkY/uq46C_xQwbEJ) mailing list, which links to WebRTC bug 1846.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to change value of `maxBitrate` property as described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71223675/1199820