# Android native webrtc app stream quality

Tags: android, webrtc

I have a problem with android application using WebRTC. In general everything is working correctly but on some devices quality of the stream is terrible. I am using io.pristine:libjingle:9127@aar lib to establish webrtc connection - it is compiled version of official webrtc android lib.

For example on Nexus 5 video quality is awesome with 20-25% usage of CPU. 
On SE SP quality is terrible, CPU arround 50% (so still some power available). 
Both devices working on the same WiFi network.

As far as I know WebRTC should pick video quality by its own, but is there any way to do it manually ?

Comment: "any way to do it manually", well yes! You can set constraints to "cap" the quality, giving you more control over what the library tries to scale up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following on IOS to limit the framerate and resolution, giving the library more room to scale bitrate instead.

```
// initialize video constraints
NSMutableArray *m = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *o = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[m addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minWidth" value:@"640"]];
[m addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"minHeight" value:@"480"]];
[m addObject:[[RTCPair alloc] initWithKey:@"maxFrameRate" value:@"20"]];

// init the constraints object
APP.videoConstraints = [[RTCMediaConstraints alloc] initWithMandatoryConstraints:m optionalConstraints:o];
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for helping ! I also recomending a way to increase bandwitch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712224/how-to-control-bandwidth-in-webrtc-video-call

Answer (score 1):

It seems that controlling bandwidth via constraints are deprecated for now.

So, at least in version *GoogleWebRTC (1.1.31999)* for iOS and *org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.22672* for android there is method in **PeerConnection** instance.

For iOS:

```
let updateBitrateSuccessful = pc.setBweMinBitrateBps(300000, currentBitrateBps: 1000000, maxBitrateBps: 3000000)
print("Update rtc connection bitrate " + (updateBitrateSuccessful ? "successful" : "failed"))
```

Respectively, for Android:

```
boolean updateBitrateSuccessful = pc.setBitrate(300000, 1000000, 3000000);
Log.d("AppLog", "Update rtc connection bitrate " + (updateBitrateSuccessful ? "successful" : "failed"));
```