# Switching between different camera resolution while live streaming with WebRTC

Tags: c#, networking, webrtc, live-streaming, bandwidth

I have build a basic C# app, which uses a wrapper that facilitate WebRTC functions in C# app. Though this works just fine, but I couldn't get logic for switching between different camera resolution depending upon available bandwidth.

Although I did found few article that states the option in WebRTC to limit the use of bandwidth ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712224/how-to-control-bandwidth-in-webrtc-video-call)), but the following two things are still unclear to me:

- switching between different camera resolution
- correlating the resolution to bandwidth availability

Comment: You don't actually want to change the camera capture resolution, as this takes time... it's not immediate, and you need to be able to scale up/down quickly as bandwidth and CPU allow.  What you do is scale the image being sent through the codec.  In any case, what WebRTC stack are you using in your app?  It probably does this for you... these things are monoliths and don't really give the developer much control.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, what you say make sense.

Would you be able to point to any good resource to read specifically on this topic. The app works fine, I am just curious about logic behind it and what are the standard for live streaming and resolution dependencies of it.

Comment: There are no good resources that I know of.  Your best bet is to read the source code for one of the implementations.  This is not trivial.  Also, consider joining the video-dev Slack group.  There's a #webrtc channel.