# How to increase the bitrate of webrtc?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm using webrtc to send a 1080p video stream from one tab to another tab on the same computer(windows10, chrome 76). And the receiver's video quality is not as good as sender's. The bitrate is only about 2400kbps(300kb/s), no difference between 1080p and 720p. Video resolution also become lower when the camera moving.
How can I improve the quality of webrtc video stream?

I have tried to modify sdp to increase bitrate. http://www.rtcbits.com/2016/11/controlling-bandwidth-usage-in-webrtc.html

set `x-google-max-bitrate`

```
peer.createAnswer().then(sdp => {
  var arr = sdp.sdp.split('\r\n');
  arr.forEach((str, i) => {
    if (/^a=fmtp:\d*/.test(str)) {
      arr[i] = str + ';x-google-max-bitrate=28000;x-google-min-bitrate=0;x-google-start-bitrate=20000';
    }
  });
  sdp = new RTCSessionDescription({
    type: 'answer',
    sdp: arr.join('\r\n'),
  })
  peer.setLocalDescription(sdp);
  socket.emit('message_send', { type: 'answer', sdp: sdp.sdp });
});
```

output receive rate (kb/s)

```
var prevReport = null;
var t = setInterval(function() {
  if (!peer) {
    prevReport = null;
    return;
  }
  peer.getStats(null).then(reporter => {
    reporter.forEach(report => {
      if (report.type === 'inbound-rtp' && report.mediaType === 'video') {
        if (!prevReport) {
          prevReport = report;
        } else {
          console.log((report.bytesReceived - prevReport.bytesReceived) / (report.timestamp - prevReport.timestamp));
        }
      }
    });
  });
}, 1000);
```

I hope that the bitrate of 1080p could be obviously greater than of 720p.
Is there a way to let webrtc transport lossless or low-loss video stream?

---

The 300kb/s limit only exists when a chrome tab sends video to another chrome tab. When a chrome tab sends video to a firefox tab, the `x-google-max-bitrate` works.

Comment: also got a link for future reference http://www.rtcbits.com/2016/11/controlling-bandwidth-usage-in-webrtc.html

Comment: this will allow you control bitrate during a call https://stackoverflow.com/a/74600584/12771945

Answer (score 11):

I tried to set `b=AS:10000` and it works.

```
peer.createAnswer().then(sdp => {
  var arr = sdp.sdp.split('\r\n');
  arr.forEach((str, i) => {
    if (/^a=fmtp:\d*/.test(str)) {
      arr[i] = str + ';x-google-max-bitrate=10000;x-google-min-bitrate=0;x-google-start-bitrate=6000';
    } else if (/^a=mid:(1|video)/.test(str)) {
      arr[i] += '\r\nb=AS:10000';
    }
  });
  sdp = new RTCSessionDescription({
    type: 'answer',
    sdp: arr.join('\r\n'),
  })
  peer.setLocalDescription(sdp);
  socket.emit('message_send', { type: 'answer', sdp: sdp.sdp });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Helped me to record HD video with Kurento media server. I tried to call `webRtcEndpoint.setMaxVideoRecvBandwidth()` and `recorderEndpoint.setMaxOuputBitrate()` but it wan't enough.

Comment: Works like a charm! Must combine with field `x-google-max-bitrate` to work.

Answer (score 5):

Correct way for adjusting audio and video bandwidth limitation is shown in the official sample
https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth

Here is simplified example for setting video bandwidth limitation 1 Mbps with [maxBitrate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCRtpEncodingParameters/maxBitrate) property of `RTCRtpEncodingParameters`:

```js
const pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(servers);

...

const sender = pc1.getSenders()[0];
const parameters = sender.getParameters();
parameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate = 1 * 1000 * 100;
sender.setParameters(parameters);
```

For adjusting audio bandwidth limitation corresponding sender should be updated, e.g.

```js
const sender = pc1.getSenders()[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having trouble setting `maxBitrate` with `getSenders()`. Specifically if your `setParameters()` seems to go through successfully (returned promise gets resolved without an error), but the video bitrate doesn't change.

The problem is that every answer on this topic (even the [official example](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/bandwidth/)) seems to assume that the video track will be the `[0]` in the array of `getSenders()`. After hours of pulling my hair, I found out that the order of tracks is not defined by the specification (that is even [noted in the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getSenders#:%7E:text=The%20order%20of%20the%20returned%20RTCRtpSender%20instances%20is%20not%20defined%20by%20the%20specification%2C%20and%20may%20change%20from%20one%20call%20to%20getSenders()%20to%20the%20next.)), so your video track could be anywhere in the array.

To solve this you just need to iterate through the return of `getSenders()` and look for the `track.kind` you want to change:

```
const maxBitrateInBitsPerSecond = 75000
const senders = peerConnection.getSenders()

senders.forEach((sender) => {
    if (sender.track.kind === 'video'){
        // Change bitrate for video track here
        const parameters = sender.getParameters()
        if (!parameters.encodings) {
            parameters.encodings = [{}]
        }
        parameters.encodings[0].maxBitrate = maxBitrateInBitsPerSecond
        sender.setParameters(parameters).then(() => {
            console.log('Bitrate changed successfuly');
        }).catch(e => console.error(e))
    }
    if (sender.track.kind === 'audio'){
        // Change bitrate for audio track here
    }
})
```